# Android ListView Show Wrong Position

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a problem with `ListView`. Here the code of adapter :

```
public class AdapterListViewEncyclopedia extends ArrayAdapter<Apple> {

    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;
    private List<Apple> data;
    private CellHolder holder;

    public AdapterListViewEncyclopedia(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Apple> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }


    static class CellHolder
    {
        ImageView imageApple;
        TextView tvCellAppleName;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new CellHolder();
            holder.imageApple = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageApple);
            holder.tvCellAppleName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvAppleName);

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(InterfaceConfig.serverURL+data.get(position).getImageURL(), holder.imageApple);


            holder.tvCellAppleName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
            System.out.println(position);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (CellHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        return row;
    }

}
```

**The Main Problem :**

1.I have 10 data in `ArrayAdapter<Apple>` and When i open page with `ListView` and i print position code with `System.out.println`, the code show 0,1,2,3,4,5,0
2. When i scroll the `ListView` , Top and Bottom which hidden is random position.

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Read your code...  When you are setting the text? Only if...

Comment: also i have no idea why those people use that infamous view holder... how much help does it give compared to problems with it?

Comment: @selvin : Sorry, i already updated the code.

Comment: @pskink : i have do it before. And it running well, but in this case i don't know why it running wrong when scrolled the page.

Comment: so where/when are you calling `setText`?

Comment: @pskink : did you mean this ? holder.tvCellAppleName.setText(data.get(position).getName());

Comment: yes i mean this

Comment: @pskink : sorry but i don't get it. So what the problem with that ?

Comment: You have to the set the data after , if else block  then u got the correct position

Comment: @Nithinlal : can you post your solution? if you right i will accept as correct answer. thank you

Comment: just setup a breakpoint in the first line of your `getView` method and see it by yourself in step-by-step debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have update the code pls try this. You have to set the data after the if-else block other wise you cannot get the correct position in the listview while binding the data. Please refer the android view holder properties 
[ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

```
public class AdapterListViewEncyclopedia extends ArrayAdapter<Apple> {

private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
private List<Apple> data;
private CellHolder holder;

public AdapterListViewEncyclopedia(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Apple> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}


static class CellHolder
{
    ImageView imageApple;
    TextView tvCellAppleName;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new CellHolder();
        holder.imageApple = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageApple);
        holder.tvCellAppleName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvAppleName);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CellHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    // you can set the data here 
    setData(position,holder);

    return row;
}
private void setData(int position, CellHolder holder)
{
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(InterfaceConfig.serverURL+data.get(position).getImageURL(), holder.imageApple);

    holder.tvCellAppleName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
}
}
```

Comment: It works with little lag when update the image on the ListView. btw thanks.

Comment: use glide to load image its faster than Image loader

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.